# Swizzle a class method and a instance method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, runtime, swizzling

I have some weird requirement to swizzle a class method with an instance method.

Basically, they are in different classes A & B. A has a static function called

```
 public static func aTest() {}
```

B is a singleton with a function

```
 static let sharedInstance = B()
```

And it has a function

```
 public func bTest() {}
```

How can I swizzle out aTest() and point to B.sharedInstance.bTest()?

I know it is a very weird request .. but I need this :)

Comment: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ for info on method swizzling

Comment: @joslinm thanks for your reply, i have read that blog a dozen of times but this case is different.

Comment: You should learn to listen and how to be constructive. Talking about unrelated things and being like this is not helpful at all.